# histogram is not visible using matplotlib and would like to group values in the x axis within intervals

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, histogram

I would like to plot a histogram but the problem is that my histogram is not visible. Here is what my histogram looks like:
[image]

I would like to use the following intervals within my axis:  [-1,0] ]0,1], ]1,2]]2,4],]4,8],]8,16],]16,32]

Here is the code I am using:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

x = ['0',   '1',  '2',   '3', '4',  '5',   '6','7',   '8', '9','10','11','12','13','14','15','16','17','18','19','20','21','22','23','24','25','26','27','28','29','30','31','32','33','34','35','36','38','40','41','42','43','44','45','48','50','51','53','54','57','60','64','70','77','93','104','108','147'] 
y=  ['164','189','288','444','311','216','122','111','92','54','45','31','31','30','18','15','15','10','4','15','2','8','6','4','7','5','3','3','1','10','3','3','3','2','4','2','1','1','1','2','2','1','1','1','1','1','2','1','2','2','2','1','1','2','1','1','1','1']
x = [int(i) for i in x]
y = [int(i) for i in y]
plt.bar(x, y)
    
plt.xlabel('Variable accesses')
plt.ylabel('Number of Variables')
plt.show()
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: you want to zoom in `x axis` ? what do you mean by `I would like to use the following intervals within my axis: [-1,0] ]0,1], ]1,2]]2,4],]4,8],]8,16],]16,32] ` ? Could you please explain ?

Comment: Sounds like an x-y problem (no pun intended). How did you end up with these string lists? Wouldn't it be easier to create a numpy/pandas histogram with the desired bins in the original array/dataframe? BTW, bins usually exclude the end, not the start of the interval. Would make your life easier if you redefined your bins according to what the libraries support.

Comment: instead of having one bin for each data point, I would like to sum up the values corresponding to each data point and represent them as an interval. For example, ]4,8] would have as a value the sum of data points 5, 6, 7, 8 which is in this case 216+122+111+92

Comment: This is understood and easy to implement. However, doing so would be bad advice, unless these string lists are provided by a third party, and you cannot influence what you receive.

Comment: I think you can do a better job at explaining what you're aiming for. Try to use a shorter dataframe, and explain in a symblic way. And, also you don't need to give pandas string data types, and then use a `int()` function to change the data type. Just create your dataframe with the number in the first place.

Comment: Try `plt.bar(x, y,log=True)` it will scale your data and some points might be visible, however I didn't understand what scale you want???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create lists with the interval labels and the corresponding sums:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20',
     '21', '22', '23', '24', '25', '26', '27', '28', '29', '30', '31', '32', '33', '34', '35', '36', '38', '40', '41',
     '42', '43', '44', '45', '48', '50', '51', '53', '54', '57', '60', '64', '70', '77', '93', '104', '108', '147']
y = ['164', '189', '288', '444', '311', '216', '122', '111', '92', '54', '45', '31', '31', '30', '18', '15', '15', '10',
     '4', '15', '2', '8', '6', '4', '7', '5', '3', '3', '1', '10', '3', '3', '3', '2', '4', '2', '1', '1', '1', '2',
     '2', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '2', '1', '2', '2', '2', '1', '1', '2', '1', '1', '1', '1']
x = [int(xi) for xi in x]
y = [int(yi) for yi in y]
start = -1
end = 0
intervals = []
values = []
while end < 2 * max(x):
    intervals.append(f'$]{start},{end}]$')
    values.append(sum([yi for xi, yi in zip(x, y) if start < xi <= end]))
    start = end
    end = 1 if end == 0 else 2 * end

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 4))
ax.bar(intervals, values)

ax.set_xlabel('Variable accesses')
ax.set_ylabel('Number of Variables')
ax.margins(x=0.02)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]